# Solidity Import Multiple Declarations

Tags: solidity, erc20

I need to use external contracts (AAVE) so to call their methods I import them. Nevertheless, this import conflicts with the previous ERC20 Declaration and I have the next error:

```
browser/Project.sol:10:1: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared. import "https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IAToken.sol"; ^----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^ https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.3.0/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol:8:1: The previous declaration is here: interface IERC20 { ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the second import and still use the IERC20 interface as it is already imported by the first import.